# Change specific index without re-render whole array in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

In a **Vuejs** project, I have an **array** in my **data object** and render it in view with a `v-for` directive. now if I change a specific index in that array, Vue re-render the whole array in view. is there any way to see changes in view without re-render the whole array?

---

the reason behind this question is that other indexes of my array processing or doing something and when the whole array re-render in view, these processes are stopped.

Comment: Can you add what ever code you tried so far ..

Comment: codes don't explain anything more than these words in this question my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 1.x we have `track-by="$index"` to track changed index in rendered array. but since version 2.x, Vue suggest using `:key` when we rendering array in view with `v-for` intead `track-by="$index"`. but consider this blow example:

**In `<template>` :**

```js
<div v-for="(doc, i) in docs" :key="i">
 <h4>{{ doc.status }}</h4>
 <button @click="reject(i)"> Reject </button>
</div>
```

**In `<script>` :**

```js
data: {
 docs: [
  { status: 'pending' },
  { status: 'pending' },
  { status: 'pending' }
 ]
},

methods: {
 reject(index) {
  this.docs[index] = { status: 'rejected' }
 }
}
```

in this example, when we change an index, Although array changes but we can't see any change in view. that's because our component rendered before and we need to update its view. for this we need to use `this.$forceUpdate()` in our method to update the component.

```js
reject(index) {
 this.docs[index] = { status: 'rejected' }
 this.$forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Downvoting as most of this (self)answer is simply wrong. First: reason the Vue does not update the view after above array change is that Vue 2 can't detect change when you directly set an item with the index - see [Change Detection Caveats For Arrays](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays). Second: `key` is important yes, but it does not change the fact that if you have a `v-for` over an array in the template, it always renders **all** items in the array. See [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603075/381282) for more details...