# Vue js input in table row inside v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-table

I've this situation:

- a v-for that create all the rows in a table
- a v-if that decide if the row is visible or not

in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3adx12p6/1/) i've created an example.

If i change the value in only one input the v-if is re-executed for all the rows (with a huge amount of data to check in the v-if method it slows a lot when an user type into the input.)

My issue is that it re-executes the v-if for all the rows but i need it executed only for the current row. Is there any solution to that ? I think that it's a normal behavior of Vue but with a heavy method on the v-if, the user is blocked (image that he types 3 letter in the input with a table of 100 rows it means 300 execution for the method inside the v-if and visually we can see that the input is working slowly)

```
    <div id="app">
      <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>input</th>
          <th>2018</th>
          <th>2017</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(sale,i) in sales[0]" :key="i" v-if="isItemGood(sale)">
           <th scope="row">{{ sale.Month  }}</th>  
           <td><input v-model="asd"></input></td>
           <td>{{ sale.Sale }}</td>
           <td>{{ sales[1][i].Sale }}</td>  
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        asd: null,
        sales: [
            [{'Year': 2018, 'Month': 01, 'Sale': 512}, {'Year': 2018, 'Month': 02, 'Sale': 1025}],
                [{'Year': 2017, 'Month': 01, 'Sale': 155}, {'Year': 2017, 'Month': 02, 'Sale': 12}]
        ]
      },
      methods: {
        isItemGood(sale) {
          console.log(sale)
          return true
        }
      },
      watch: {
        asd: {
          handler(newValues) {
          }
        }
      }
    })
    <style>
    td, th { border: 1px solid red;}
    </style>
```

Comment: use a computed value instead of sales[0]

Comment: What if you place the ‘v-for’ in its own ‘template’ tag?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67600235/381282

Answer (score 0):

first, I would suggest you to use a computed method which will return the filtered array

```
computed: {
  filteredSales() {
    return this.sales[0].filter(this.isItemGood);
  }
}
```

and then iterating the v-for through the computed array.

another thing which might speed things up is using v-show instead of v-if (which doesn't really rerender), but keep in mind that this will render the items but just won't make them visible

Comment: the thing is that each row should have it's own computed (hide row1, show row2, hide row3 for example and i think that it's not a good idea to pass parameters to a computed method)