# Vue - How to re-render specific array object change without re-render entire array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for, vue-reactivity

I have been looking for this answer for a long time now. Finally posting it since I have a problem related to this.

Please check this below code snippet

```
<div>
    <template v-for="(row, index) in rows">
         <tr v-if="hasChildData(row, index)" :key="`row-${tabId}-${index}`">
              <!-- Rest of the logic -->
         </tr>
    </template>
</div>
```

Method

```
hasChildData(row, index) {
  console.log("Looping index: "+ index);
  return row.childData;
}
```

Lets say rows is an array and has 5 elements

```
data() {
    return {
      rows: [
        { test: 123 },
        { test: 345 },
        { test: 567 },
        { test: 789 },
        { test: 904 },
      ]
   };
}
```

Somewhere i try to update a specific row in rows array. In this case index 3

```
setChildData() {
    Vue.set(this.rows[3], "childData", true);
}
```

Why does Vue re-render the entire loop. Is there a way to only re-render specific index only 3 ?
This is related to [Change specific index without re-render whole array in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579468/change-specific-index-without-re-render-whole-array-in-vuejs) but didn't find the answer what i was looking for.

Output After calling setChildData():

Looping index: 0

Looping index: 1

Looping index: 2

Looping index: 3

Looping index: 4

While I Expect

Looping index: 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603075/381282

Comment: Move all things that you don't want to be rerendered to nested components. It rerenders current component, not specifically a loop.